# 'Content-Length too' long when uploading file using Tornado

Tags: file-upload, tornado

Using a slightly modified version of this [Tornado upload app](https://github.com/vamsiikrishna/tornado-upload) on my development machine, I get the following error from tornado server and a blank page whenever I try to upload large files (+100MB):

> [I 130929 07:45:44 httpserver:330] Malformed HTTP request from
>   127.0.0.1: Content-Length too long

There is no problem uploading files up to ~20MB.

so I'm wondering whether there is any particular file upload limit in Tornado web server? Or does it have someting to do with the machine's available memory. And whatever the reason is, how can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tornado has a configurable limit on upload size (defaulting to 10MB).  You can increase the limit by passing `max_buffer_size` to the `HTTPServer` constructor (or `Application.listen`).  However, since Tornado (version 3.1) reads the entire upload body into a single contiguous string in memory, it's dangerous to make the limit too high.  One popular alternative is the [nginx upload module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadModule).

Comment: In tornadoweb 4 we have the tornado.web.stream_request_body decorator, nginx is not required anymore.

Comment: The default is now 100mb (Tornado v. 4.4.1 as of the date of this comment)